# How to join two tables in Pyrocms

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, join, pyrocms

I am new to pyrocms, I want to join two tables in pyrocms.
My two tables are milege and products. How to join this two table in pyrocms
What I have tried is:

```
 {% set table_data=query().from('milege).join('products').on('milege.id','=','product.mid').where('user_id','1').get() %}
```

I am getting errors on executing this query. How to join these two table data in pyrocms.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a single quote in your code, but to answer your question, it mirrors the [Laravel query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins):

```
{% set results = query().from('mileage').join('products', 'milege.id', '=', 'product.mid').where('user_id','1').get() %}
```